# Plugged my US(110v) Fender Rumble into EU(240v) socket

Tags: amplifiers

For reasons I wont go into I accidentally fried my amp.
My question: Is it possible to fix? I know sometimes the Power transistor 'blows'.
At the moment the LED doesn't even light up.
I'd like to replace whatever it takes rather than just buy a new one.

Can anyone guide me on how to resistance check from the power plug forward to the power transistor or is it nigh on impossible to do this ?

Comment: First check any internal fuses.

Answer (score 1):

There's going to be a few components between the mains input and the power transistor!   With any luck, the first thing you'll find after the power socket is a fuse.  With even more luck, it's blown - and that's ALL that's blown.  Beyond that, take it to a repair shop.  It'll be cheaper in the end.

Answer (score 1):

You’re confusing transistor with transformer! A transistor amplifies, the power transistors in an amp are near the very end of a long and complicated circuit.

The first thing the mains power hits when you plug it in is a transformer that separates the mains voltage into the 2 or 3 different voltages the amp will run off. This is the thing that was expecting 110v but you gave it 230v.

As others have said, with any luck there will be a fuse, likely a glass one, in that initial loop between the mains input, on switch and transformer ‘primary’ coil. SOME modern amps have an annoying fuse built into the transformer which is next to impossible to replace. Hopefully you don’t have that and can see a glass fuse in a little holder somewhere near where the power comes into the amp. When checking this make sure the amp is fully unplugged. ***This part of the circuit is live with mains voltage whenever it’s plugged in, even if the amp is switched off.***

If you can see it’s blown look for the rating stamp on one end of it. It will probably say something like 250v T2a or similar. The 250v is nothing to do with uk or us mains, it just means that if it blows it will guarantee breaking the circuit up to 250v. The important thing to match is the amp rating (eg. 2a or 2A), replace with exactly the same. Note the T next to the amp rating. T means timed, also called slow-blow, meaning it won’t blow when you get a brief spike of current when you turn the amp on, if it doesn’t say T it’s just a normal medium speed fuse. You also see F which means fast acting, and other markings which, if you come across, are worth a Google, but in that part of the circuit it’ll probably just be a T.

It’s easy enough to find glass fuses in all specs all over the web, just make sure you replace with EXACTLY the same fuse. Failure to do so will result in the fuse instantly blowing again, or the amp potentially frying itself to death being allowed to run in a fault condition without the fuse doing its job.

If the fuse blows again, or the amp still doesn’t work then it is not something you will be able to fix on your own. Conventional wisdom says suspect the transformer last, but in truth that’s mainly because diagnosing a transformer fault is not straight forward, and a new transformer is expensive and requires skill to fit. Ie, exhaust all other possibilities before trying to diagnose a faulty transformer. To exhaust all other possibilities you need to be good at safely testing rail voltages when the amp is open and turned on, DO NOT DO THIS unless taught how to do it safely and probably under observation the first few times.

Transformers don’t have a huge amount you can test them on, they are two (or a few more) coils of wire with relatively low resistance per coil when working, when blown they appear much the same, the only way you can tell from a resistance reading that your 18 Ohm primary coil is shorted is knowing that before it was shorted it used to read 24 Ohm. Transformers come in a vast array of types, usually fairly bespoke to a particular family of amps from a manufacturer, there’s no standard reading you can expect to measure without having the exact data sheet of the transformer you have.

A lightbulb limiter is often used ‘in the trade’ to diagnose a faulty transformer but you have to make that and get to know how to read its behaviours. Failing that you just have to get a schematic, identify the two primary wires and the 3-10+ secondary wires (and which ones are paired, or have centre tap), disconnect it all from the circuit and test you’re getting the expected input and output voltages. Again this is dangerous, sometimes complicated work, and you have to put it back together correctly or it will definitely fry something.

In short, check the fuse, if it’s not that, take it to a good tech! It’s unlikely to be completely ruined, though if it comes to a new transformer it could be an annoying bill.